# How to turn on numbering for subsections only?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering

I want to turn on the numbering for the table of contents for the subsections only and leave the sections unnumbered.

I turned off all the numbering using the command:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
```

However, This turns the numbering off for both sections and subsections.

I am using document class article.

Comment: In the body of the document, you also want sections to be unnumbered and the subsedtion counter to be reset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\patchcmd{\subsection}{2}{\value{secnumdepth}}{}{}

%one could use this
%\counterwithout{subsection}{section}
%or maybe this
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Foo}
\subsection{Foo bar}
\subsection{Foo baz}
\section{Foo}
\subsection{Foo bar}
\end{document}
```

If you want to reset subsection numbering with section you need to add

```
\makeatletter 
\patchcmd{\@sect}{\@empty}{\@empty\stepcounter{#1}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: you're welcome :-)